# How to get in Controller input text?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have something like that:

```
<?php echo "<form><input style="."text"." id="."email"."name="."email"." placeholder="."email".">"
```

How can i send this email to ProductController?
I am trying like that:

```
 $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
         var_dump($var = $data['email']);
```

But it didin't work, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can get value with :

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('email');
```

or

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('email');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a form with an empty `action` and empty `type` and hence it won't send request to any controller when you submit your form.

If you want to properly direct your from to a controller action, then you need to do this:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('catalog/product/{method}') ?> method="POST"></form>
```

Please note, I don't know to which method you want to redirect your form hence I put `method`.

So in your product controller (I recommend you have a rewrite controller for `ProductController.php`), you need a method like this:

```
public function methodAction()
{
    $email = $this->getRequest()->getPost('email);
}
```

I doubt you miss with some important concepts in Magento. If you think so, please grab it first. Happy Coding.

Comment: it doesn't work for me <form action=<?php echo "".$this->getUrl('catalog/product/{method}')."" ?> method="POST"><input type="text" id="email" name=email" placeholder="email">
               <?php endif;?>
               <?php echo "<button><a href="."sub/product/subthis/id/".$id.">Send e-mail Action</a></form>"?>

Comment: Please re-read the answer. I didnt provide you a copy-paste solution. You need to understand my answer first. Then change codes accordingly. With all respect, Blindly copy-pasting an answer do not improve your knowledge